Angular (18.2.10) Cant load a image
I cant add my image to the web app, when i try to load a image from a url like
<img src="http://website/img.png">
works fine but when i try to open a image on my project doesn't load
<img src="/assets/img.png">
i try with diferent images and change the path so many times to the public or other paths

I noticed that for new Angular 18 projects they've moved the default assets location in the repository from /assets to /public and the output in the final build from /assets to /.
So if you don't want to change your angular.json you should put your img.png in the /public folder in your repository.
In your template you should link to /img.png:
<img src="/img.png">


Make sure you have baseHref set in your project.
<base href="/">

Then you create an assets folder and make sure you add it in the angular.json inside the assets array.
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      ...
      "options": {
        "assets": ["src/assets"],
        ...

Finally, you can import and use it.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <img src="/assets/download.jpg"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

After doing these changes, I had to restart my application for the changes to take effect.
Stackblitz Demo
